# My kitten was desexed young?

Tags: cats, desexing

I got my 10 week old kitten yesterday and he was desexed 3 days before that. That seems too young. Wondering what effects this could have on his hormones, personality and development?

Comment: While the question http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1848 is similar, it's about the *recommended* age for desexing a cat. This question is about the effect of early desexing. Since early desexing is becoming common in shelters, I think it's good to address this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need to worry. The [ASPCA](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/general-pet-care/spayneuter-your-pet) says:

> It is generally considered safe for kittens as young as eight weeks
>   old to be spayed or neutered. In animal shelters, surgery is often
>   performed at this time so that kittens can be sterilized prior to
>   adoption.

Answer (score 3):

All is good! SPCA's spay/neuter the kittens super young, this helps them to be adopted MUCH faster. The surgery is more risky but you won't have any bad side-effects from it.

Comment: If you get a chance may post an answer at [the dupe](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1848/13) where the answers talk about months of age as opposed to weeks of age.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest effects of this is that he will (hopefully) never develop a marking habit. Cats usually start marking around the time that they go through puberty and it's more common in male cats, so it's definitely a good thing that he's fixed already