# How can we protect our female cat who gets harassed all the time by at least 6 tomcats in our garden?

Tags: cats

Our female cat is not spayed yet, she is going to be tomorrow. She has two female kittens too, they're with her all the time (they're going to be spayed as soon as they reach the minimum weight for the procedure). The mother sleeps and protects herself and the kittens in a small cave-like space in our large garden (it is a common space for multiple residences).

Lately, I have been observing at least 6 different tomcats waiting just under her nose in the entrance of her little cave. She and her kittens are naturally extremely disturbed, they cannot even get out of the cave unless I am around.

I am going to take them to the vet tomorrow for spaying (mother) and a general check. But after the mother recovers I don't know how I can put them back in the garden again. I already gave multiple ads to find home(s) to them. There has unfortunately been no return, and I have to move to another country two months later.

Do you have any suggestions for us?

Comment: Is keeping them inside full time possible? After spaying the mother should be kept in a clean and calm environment anyways, so bringing them inside might be the better option for now.

Comment: I wish it were possible. But as I said, unless they are adoped I don't want to keep them in my house since I will move out to a different country soon. The vet said he would have to keep them at the clinic until the mother recovers. After they are discharged, I plan to keep them in my house for some time more. But I'll have to release them to the garden at the end. The more they got used to indoors, the more they forget the living outside. But I check and feed them every day.

Comment: Related [What are my options for re-homing my pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/what-are-my-options-for-re-homing-my-pet)

Answer (score 3):

Spaying her will help the tomcats leave her alone. **You should spay/neuter the kittens as well** - these days vets can do it as [young as 6-8 weeks.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/15929/13)

While it is sad that you might have to leave them behind when you move, many cats live outdoor lives happily and may find another family to live with on their own after you're gone. It is good that you're trying to find them a home, and you may still have success before you leave.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider getting one of those KittyWalk enclosures. They're small enclosures that would enable your pet to be outdoors without being harassed by those tomcats. They're like industrial strength, fishnet weaved dog houses, but for cats.