# Do cats commit incest?

Tags: cats, behavior

Do cats commit incest? If so, at what age would this behavior begin, and when should male and female kittens be separated from one another so as to avoid incest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cats, like most animals, will mate with any willing member of the opposite sex. So, yes, they will sometimes inbreed. Humans have been known to encourage that when trying to select for specific genetic traits.

Rather than trying to separate them -- they can hit puberty as early as 8 months, if I remember correctly -- I strongly recommend getting them surgically neutered, unless you are raising purebreds. There are already many more cats looking for homes than homes looking for cats.

Comment: Related [What is most appropriate age to neuter/spay a cat?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1848)

Answer (score 1):

Yes unfortunately cats do inbreed. It is safe to fix your pet at any age. There are restrictions for too young and too old. Fortunately most vet practices 'screen' your pet before surgery. At our clinic we put every pet under anesthesia for the procedure. So it's best to be cautious about the pets health.  There are clinics that offer discounted or at cost fixing. You may have to travel a bit to find a clinic. Or submit financial information for consideration to see if you are eligible to get a discounted rate. We have a local clinic that does not make you jump through hoops to have your pet fixed. All they ask is that you provide proof that your pet has been vaccinated.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with "it is safe to fix your pet at any age" ...